# Android Using Barcode Scanner Zxing

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to do a barcode search withought leaving an app (i.e. opening a browser and doing a google search).  I've perused this site and others but did not find anything.  Apologies in advance if this has been covered somewhere here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. We use barcode readers in various apps. Use startActivityForResult passing an Intent specifying the zxing barcode reader class. As a result you get the scanned code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Does it actually retrieve the product info, like the title of a book etc?

Comment: It retrieves whatever is encoded in the barcode. If it is f.e. an ISBN, you need to lookup the book, if it is an URL, go to that URL, if it is a Vcard, do with it what you see fit

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely added [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to your app. The docs there describe adding it to your app as well as integrating with the Barcode Scanner app. In either case, you're going to get numeric code for the product. It is up to you to use this code. You can perform product searches on various providers like Google, Bing, Amazon, etc.

Comment: What I was wondering is it possible to pull in product info into the app without opening a browser.  Basically when the user scans a product the app seemlessly, without showing the browser lookup, displays back the product.  Don't want the user to see the search with the upc number.